# How to use a JSON file as an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I have a Javascript code that uses an array of objects as:

```
var words = [{"text":"This", "url":"http://google.com/"},
         {"text":"is", "url":"http://bing.com/"},
         {"text":"some", "url":"http://somewhere.com/"},
         {"text":"random", "url":"http://random.org/"},
         {"text":"text", "url":"http://text.com/"},
         {"text":"InCoMobi", "url":"http://incomobi.com/"},
         {"text":"Yahoo", "url":"http://yahoo.com/"}]
```

Then I use `words` in the rest of code and everything works fine.

Then I store the data in a JSON file, lets call the file "myfile.json" its content is:

```
{
"words": [
{"text":"This", "url":"http://google.com/"},
{"text":"is", "url":"http://bing.com/"},
{"text":"random", "url":"http://random.org/"},
{"text":"some", "url":"http://somewhere.com/"},
{"text":"text", "url":"http://text.com/"},
{"text":"InCoMobi", "url":"http://incomobi.com/"},
{"text":"Yahoo", "url":"http://yahoo.com/"}
]
}
```

I load this file using `d3.json` as:

```
d3.json("myfile.json", function(words) {
    console.log(words);  //Log output to console
});
```

And then I use `words` the same as before, now my code does not work!
What is the difference between the two things and how can I fix the second method that I load the file?

Comment: the 1st words is an array which contains object, the 2nd words is an object that contains a property words which is an array of objects.

Comment: How can I convert the 2nd words to something similar to 1st?

Comment: Use words.words to get the same result.

Comment: it is a little confusing. Assume instead of `{ "words": [ ...` I had `{"X": [...` then what would I use?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that the first is an array, whereas the second is an object with one property `words` containing the the array of objects in the first example.

To convert the second to the same as the first simply do:

```
d3.json("myfile.json", function(words) {

    words = words.words;
    console.log(words);  //Log output to console
});
```

Comment: I thought it is the same, but when I used what you said my 2nd method is still not working as 1st. Is there any other difference that you can think of?

Comment: This should be working. I suspect your data is not what you say. In the function, show the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(words))`.

Comment: Here is what I get: `[{"text":"This","url":"http://google.com/"},{"text":"is","url":"http://bing.com/"},{"text":"some","url":"http://somewhere.com/"},{"text":"random","url":"http://random.org/"},{"text":"text","url":"http://text.com/"},{"text":"InCoMobi","url":"http://incomobi.com/"},{"text":"Yahoo","url":"http://yahoo.com/"}] `

Comment: That's exactly the same as your first example. It's an array of objects so either iterate over it, or directly access the objects e.g. `words[0].text`

Comment: I got a clue: when I do `console.log(words);` outside of `d3.json(...` then I get `array[0]` but when I do it inside I get `array[7]`. Looks like `words` is not defined outside of `d3.json(...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment "the 1st words is an array which contains object, the 2nd words is an object that contains a property `words` which is an array of objects".

You want to use the words property of your object, you can do this like the example below.

```
d3.json("myfile.json", function(result) {
    console.log(result.words); 
});
```

Comment: I thought it is the same, but when I used what you said my 2nd method is still not working as 1st.